# Another way to calculate double type variables in c++?

Tags: c++, double

Short version of the question: overflow or timeout in current settings when calculating large int64_t and double, anyway to avoid these?

---

Test case: 
If only demand is `80,000,000,000`, solved with correct result. But if it's `800,000,000,000`, returned incorrect `0`. 
If input has two or more demands (means more inequalities need to be calculated), smaller value will also cause incorrectness. e.g., three equal demands of `20,000,000,000` will cause the problem.

---

I'm using [COIN-OR CLP](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp) linear programming solver to solve some network flow problems. I use `int64_t` when representing the link bandwidth. But CLP uses `double` most of time and cannot transfer to other types easily.

When the values of the variables are not that large (typically smaller than 10,000,000,000) and the constraints (inequalities) are relatively few, it will give the solution I want it to. But if either of the above factors increases, the tool will stop and return a `0` value solution. I think the reason is the calculation complexity is over its maximum, so program breaks at some trivial point (it uses LP simplex method).

The inequality is some kind of:

```
totalFlowSum <= usePercentage * demand
```

I changed it to

```
totalFlowSum - usePercentage * demand <= 0
```

Since `totalFLowSum` and `demand` are very large `int64_t`, `usePercentage` is `double`, if the constraints like this are too many (several or even more), or if the demand is larger than 100,000,000,000, the returned solution will be wrong.

Is there any way to correct this, like increase the break threshold or avoid this level of calculation magnitude?

Decrease some accuracy is acceptable. I have a possible solution is that 1,000 times smaller on inputs and 1,000 time larger on outputs. But this is kind of naïve and may cause too much code modification in the program.

---

Update:
I have changed the formulation to

```
totalFlowSum / demand - usePercentage <= 0
```

but the problem still exists.

---

Update 2:
I divided `usePercentage` by 1000, making its coefficient from 1 to 0.001, it worked. But if I also divide `totalFlowSum/demand` by 1000 simultaneously, still no result. I don't know why...

Comment: I suspect the problem is related somehow to losing precision in the `double` values when the total flow sum is close to the demand modified by the use percentage.  The revision doesn't help because it really doesn't change the calculation.  Normally, it is considered that a `double` will hold 15 decimal digits or more (1E15 or so); it is surprising to me that you are running into problems at values as small as a mere 1E11.  What sort of value is the user percentage? Is it actually a fraction, or do you need to divide by 100 somewhere along the line? What sort of value is demand and total flow?

Comment: Have you considered using: `totalFlowSum <= (int64_t)(userPercentage * demand)`?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, About your first comment, if they're close, the fraction should be close to 1, now it just equal to 0. For the 2nd comment, I can't just cast it to int64_t, since the solver restricts the type to double, as its function argument.

Comment: I have to change the inequalities like `a*x_1 + b*x_2 <= 0`, and add those to the solver such that it can recognize and solve it. Simply add all the `x` variables to the left, that's those LP solvers need.

Comment: The RHS of the constraints must be a constant, and all the `x` variables be at LHS. Let me see if it's operable to change it to `(double)totalFlowSum / (double)demand - userPercentage <=0`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand which are the '`x` variables' and which are the analogues of `a` and `b`. I'm guessing that in `totalFlowSum` is one of the `x`'s; `demand` is the other, and the coefficients are `1.0` and `userPercentage`.  Is using `long double` an option?  Would it provide greater accuracy on your machine?  If so, can you convert the `int64_t` values to `long double` before doing the calculations?

Comment: Please do provide a **complete but minimal example**. I suspect that the description given is not quite accurate. In the expression shown all values will first be promoted to `double`, then you have a `double` calculation, and it's good to about 16 significant digits, unless you're on some really weird platform.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the rhs of equalities from `0` to `0.1`, the problem is then solved! Since the inputs are very large, `0.1` offset won't impact the solution at all. 
I think the reason is that previous coeffs are badly scaled, so the complier failed to find an exact answer.